# Sublime text 2 : compile problems python

Tags: python, build

{

```
import random

random.seed(0)

def rollDie():
    """returns a randomly chosen int between 1 and 6"""
    return random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6])
}
```

So what I am having problems is when I compile this python file by 'ctrl + b' and try to execute the function rollDie()  via the python console, it gives me an error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 1, in 
>   NameError: name 'rollDie' is not defined

But when I use execfile('lecture1.py') ie my file name in the console. Then it executes fine. just that when I use ctrl + B(normal build) , it throws me the traceback error. I know It is a slight mistake somewhere but can't seem to get it.

What I want is to build my file normally and then call the function normally from the console and not compile again using execfile command.

Comment: What are the curly braces for. And you didn't call the function in the example you provided. --» rollDie() should be your last line.

Comment: This is actually my first question at stack overflow, hence a little bit wrong in font. There are no braces in the code as such. I am having problem using sublime text

Comment: I ran your code just fine with sublime 2, I just added a print rollDie() to the end

Comment: Python doesn't compile either. Its interpreted. You can't call the function from the console (terminal I assume) you haven't created a module, nor is the file located in the standard python library at the moment. So opening up terminal and typing import rollDie() will not work.

Comment: Take a look on how modules work https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html also, python isn't built, sounds like you're coming from a compiled language like c, c++, or java. Those languages are in a different family of programming languages.

Comment: Also the execfile command isn't compiling anything. It's running the python file. It's no different then opening terminal or command prompt and typing python file.py it's just running your file. You will have to create a module, and store your module in the same path as the python environment you are using to be able to import it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works just fine. Somethings to note --> You don't need to provide a seed when using choice, it will "randomly" pick an element from a list.  Using `range()` you can generate a list which is the same as [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].   Remember range() won't generate 1-6 if you write `range(1,6)` The last number is excluded. Lastly, if you write a method and want use it, remember to "call" it.

```
from random import choice

def roll_die():
    return choice(range(1,7))
print roll_die()
```

Comment: oh..It's my bad. I know there is nothing wrong with my code, I just gave an example. I had the problem with Sublime text. I wanted to use it's interpreter but I was facing this problem where I needed to compile and use the function but could not.